# Files in folders in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I was wondering if there's a way to include files in folders in the search results of a document library search in sharepoint online?

For example, let's say I have a document library 'Library W' and I have a folder say 'Folder x' in it and in folder x I have a file 'FileY', is there anyway for fileY to appear in the search results of a search done in Library W?

Comment: Documents should appear in search results regardless of which folder they're in. Are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: @Thriggle Yes,indeed. The document doesn't appear when I type the name partially

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about searching, not filtering? Searching uses the search box to potentially search all of SharePoint, landing you on a search results page with refiners and previews and the like. Filtering takes place without leaving the page on which the list is displayed.

Comment: I am talking about searching. If I type a partial document name, I don't get results.

Comment: But documents that are not in folders do appear when you search for a partial name?

Comment: No, they don't for me. I need to type the entire document name to find it, which partly defeats the purpose of search.